# What happens to sse commands on a chip that doesn't support them?

Tags: c++

Lets say I write a function using _mm_fmadd_ss, as far as I know, most(if not all) AMD chips don't support that or have their own version.

What happens to the software when ran on one of these chips? Could I compile for multiple chips? How would the program choose between them?

At first I thought "oh I'll just do preprocessor #ifdef whatever" but then I realized that only the stuff that passes those conditions during preprocessing of the code makes it to the output.

Comment: use the CPUID instruction or an interface for provided by the OS; see Agner Fog's site for more information; if an instruction is not supported, and invalid instruction exception is raised by the processor

Comment: You will get invalid instruction exception, and your program will crash. Intel compiler can automatically generate code paths for multiple CPU targets, and switch them at runtime. For a generic solution, you'd have to implement that yourself.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program will usually terminate or won't execute at all, if it contains invalid instructions. One way to write portable SIMD code is to use gcc's [vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), but you still need to set a valid target architecture. On the other hand, if you run your code in a virtual machine, that supports the instructions, the code may run just fine, even if the host CPU does not support the instructions. I regularly test NEON code on a x86 computer under QEMU, for example. Also, people have ported BOCHS onto android and run x86 code (+SSE) on ARM-powered mobile phones.